# Saving a dataframe as text file without using databricks API

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I dont want use the databricks API because we are running into few issues .

I want to convert the DF to RDD and from RDD to textfile in java 1.7, Spark 1.6.2

I want my dataframe to saved as a textfile for that I know the below code works if we are using Java 1.8

```
df.rdd.map(row => row.mkString("\t")).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("outputDirRdd")
```

But im trying to put the same above code in with Java 1.7 I was unable to get the correct syntax and struck with the below code.

```
df.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<???,???>() {
        public ???  call(?? input) throws Exception {

        ?????

        }
    }).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/s/filelocation");
```

I don't know whether the above code is correct or not.

Please help me from this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for using Java 1.7 with Apache Spark for the use case mentioned is as follows:

```
df.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(Row o) throws Exception {
                        return o.mkString("\t");
                    }
                }).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/s/filelocation");
```

Here `Row`, which is `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` is the input data type and `String` is the output data type.

The `call` function will take `Row` as input parameter and return `String` as output. That's why the signature of `call` is `public String call(Row o) throws Exception {}`.

Comment: Thanks for the update himanshu. I already tried that but Im getting task not serialized error and for that I implemented the serializable interface and still getting the same issue Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Comment: Can you provide the Error Stack Trace ?

Comment: Never mind. the serialization issue was fixed when i created a separate class instead of anonymous class. Thanks :)

Comment: @BadBoy777 Do you have an example of your created class you made that fixed it for others running into the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Synthe 
This is how the issue is solved.

This below peace of code ran me into serialization issues for all its super classes and there are few classes where i cannot change them.

```
df.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, String>() {
                public String call(Row v1) throws Exception {
                    return v1.mkString("\t");
                }
            }).saveAsTextFile("/s/filelocation");
```

So for that the workaround is below:

```
df.toJavaRDD().map(new SeprateCls).saveAsTextFile("/s/filelocation");
```

The below code is the creation of seprateCls

```
public class SeprateCls implements Function<Row, String>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -635027754589291L;

public String call(Row v1) throws Exception {
    return v1.mkString("\t");
}

}
```